# CM Note 2 Stuck Rebooting After Enabling Simulate External Screen

Tags: cyanogenmod

My Verizon Galaxy Note 2 running a nightly from a couple weeks ago is stuck rebooting over and over after I enabled the option in the developer tools to simulate an external screen. I selected the bottom option that mentioned 1080p. It immediately went to the CyanogenMod booting animation. Here's the sequence that repeats forever:

It shows the booting animation for about how long it usually shows it when booting normally. Then it shows a black screen with one white, pink, or red (seemingly randomly) pixel in the very top left corner. After a couple seconds it shows another black screen and some of the top right icons (battery and clock) appear quickly. Sometimes it loads the clock and a few other elements. Then it repeats by jumping to the loading screen.

When turning the phone on after pulling the battery out, a dim light above the phone flashes red quickly.

I can get into Odin mode. Buttons don't do anything on the phone while in the perpetual boot loop.

Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it by booting into safe mode by holding the volume up button while it booted. Then I disabled the setting that broke it.